# Замкнутость множества из книги Кострикин А.И. 1977 г

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

помогите понять элементарную алгебру.

В книге Введение в Алгебру Кострикина А.И. есть утверждение.

Множество S = {4k+1 | k = 0, 1, 2 ...}. Оно замкнуто относительно умножения 
(4k1 + 1)(4k2+1) = 4k3 + 1

Подставляя k, в это выражение получаем 1*5 = 9, не понимаю, что означает замкнутость здесь?

Из определения замкнутости: Множество A называется замкнутым относительно операции *, если результат применения этой операции к любым элементам множества A также является элементом множества A. В данном выражение мы это не наблюдаем.

Comment: Почему же, наблюдаем. 9=2*4+1

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, теперь стало понятно. Знак = я так понимаю здесь это не равенство, а эквивалентность, верно?

Comment: Да. Умножение чисел такого вида дает число такого же вида.

Comment: В данном случае равенство - просто в вашей формуле  `(4k1 + 1)(4k2+1) = 4k3 + 1` (как и в моем ответе) получается `k3 = 4*k1*k2+k1+k2...` Так что 1*5=5, а не 9... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Замкнутость относительно операции означает, что для двух чисел из множества эта операция дает число из этого же множества.

В примере множество - это числа, которые при делении на 4 дают в остатке 1, а операция - умножение.

При умножении двух таких чисел вы получаете число, принадлежащее этому же множеству - т.е. дающее при делении на 4 в остатке 1...

Ваше множество - это S = {1,5,9,13...} - любое их произведение даст число, принадлежащее этому множеству, так как

```
(4k+1)*(4m+1) = 16km+4k+4m+1 = 4(4km+k+m) + 1 = 4n+1, где n = 4km+k+m...
```

Обратите внимание: в книге говорится о трех k, но не говорится, что k<sub>3</sub> - это 2 при k<sub>1</sub>=0 и k<sub>2</sub>=1... Здесь говорится о том, что для любых k<sub>1</sub> и k<sub>2</sub> найдется такое k<sub>3</sub> - ну, а я указал, как его найти :)

Так что ваш вывод, что 1*5=9 - в данном случае неверен! 1*5 = 5... Более того, дальше в книге говорится, что 9 - *квазипростое* число, т.е. не может быть получено умножением двух других чисел из этого множества...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Господин заминусовавший, в чем именно у меня ошибка?

Comment: Все понял, спасибо, постараюсь привыкнуть к такой форме записи.

Comment: Ну, если ответ понятен - можете его принять (птичка слева от ответа).